# Joining multiple tables (Following/Activity)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

**Following**

```
id
User_ID
Following_user_ID
```

The `User_ID` is following the `Following_user_ID`

**Activity**

```
A_ID
User_ID
Shared
```

(The `User_ID` column is the user that inserted the data into the tables.)

How would I build the query to select all of the activity rows where the currently logged in user is following the user in the User_ID column of Activity.

*EXAMPLE*

**Following**

```
id = 1
User_ID = 1
Following_user_ID = 2
```

User 1 is following user 2

**Activity**

```
A_ID = 1
User_ID = 2
Shared = Blah Blah
```

How can I make it so that user 1 (currently logged in) can see the activity of User 2 as user 1 is following user 2?

From the example above, user 1 should be able to see along the lines of "User 2 shared Blah Blah".

I have tried to explain this the best I can, have been trying to figure out the query but can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Activity A
JOIN Following F ON F.Following_user_ID = A.User_ID 
WHERE F.User_ID = 1
```

In case logged user is 1

Comment: This works fine, I have a column in Activity called dt_added (The date the record was added). Can I order the above statement by dt_added? Every time I try ORDER BY dt_added it breaks the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select * From following as F
join Activity as A 
on F.user_id=A.a_id
where a.user_id=1
group by following_user;
```

where 1 is the id of the user that's been followed.